# Long html page scroll snapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm developing an html page that is quite long and the design has blocks on content vertically like pages. What I want to do is when the user scrolls down the page to "snap" to a point that each page is placed correctly in centre of screen if the position of the user is within a small distance of the correct position.

We're using jquery for other things on the page so happy to use that if it has something relevant.

Any advise is of course much appreciated.

Comment: so now ,what is your question ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Usually it helps if you provide some specific information: what have you tried, what problem came up, stuff like that. You just posted a UI concept, people won't start writing code for you ;-)

Comment: Just note - in-case you started implementing my code I reworked it so it functions better.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested this but it should work. Refer to the comments for an explanation of how it works.

I disable the point after it has been snapped so that it isn't repeatedly snapped when attempting to scroll away from it. The `leniancy` variable is both the distance from the point the user must scroll before it becomes active again and the distance before a point is snapped.

```
var points = [250, 675, 1225, $("#someDiv")]; // y coordinates or jQuery objects you want to centre against.
var disabledPoints = []; // Points that you won't snap to (leave empty) this allows user to scroll from a point
var wMid = ($(window).height() / 2); // Pixels to centre of window
var leniancy = 100; // Number of pixels ether side of a point before it is snapped

$.each(points, function(key, value) { // Loop through points
   if (value instanceof jQuery) { // If value is a jQuery object
      function setObjectPos(){
         var offset = value.offset();
         var centerPoint = offset.top + (value.height() /2); // Calculate object centre relative to document
         value.data('centerPoint', centerPoint); // Store it for later
      });
      value.bind('DOMSubtreeModified', setObjectPos); // If div changes update  center position.
   }
}

$(window).resize(function () {  // If user resizes window update window mid-point variable
   wMid = ($(window).height() / 2);
});

$(window).scroll(function () { 
   var centerPos = $(window).scrollTop() + wMid; // Position of screen center relative to document
   $.each(points, function(key, value) { // Loop through points
      if (value instanceof jQuery) {
         value = value.data('centerPoint');
      }
      var offset = value - centerPos;
      if(checkDistance(offset, leniancy)) {
         snapToPoint(key); // Success! snap that point
         return false; // Kill the loop
      }
   });
   $.each(disabledPoints, function(key, value) { // Loop through disabled points
      if (value instanceof jQuery) {
         value = value.data('centerPoint');
      }
      var offset = value - centerPos;
      if(!checkDistance(offset, leniancy)) {
         enablePoint(key); // Success! enable that point
      }
   });
});

function checkDistance(offset, margin) {
   if (offset > 0) { 
      if (offset <= margin) { 
         return true;
      }
   } else {
      if (offset >= (margin * -1)) {
         return true;
      }
   }
   return false;
}

function snapToPoint(index) {
   var offset = (points[index] instanceof jQuery) ? points[index].data('centerPoint') - wMid : points[index] - wMid;
   $(window).scrollTop(offset); 
   var point = points.splice(index, 1); 
   disabledPoints.push(point[0]); 
}

function enablePoint(index) {
   var point = disabledPoints.splice(index, 1);
   points.push(point[0]); 
}​
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to respond, much appreciated. I'll give it a go and see.

Comment: @DanGrant No problem, let me know if you encounter any problems. Like I said it's not been tested so you may hit an error.